# What mods can you put in clothing in 7 Days to Die?

Tags: 7-days-to-die

Some clothing items like the Leather Duster have a mod slot in addition to the cosmetic slot, but I can't find any mods that will work with them.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the clothing items like the duster can't actually take any mods despite there being a mod slot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a couple of Versions since I played, but as I recall, there are two mods that work on clothing, the [Storage Pocket](https://7daystodie.gamepedia.com/Storage_Pocket_(Clothing)) mod (not to be confused with the [Storage Pocket](https://7daystodie.gamepedia.com/Storage_Pocket) mod which only works on armour...) and Cargo Pocket mod which Decrease encumbrance penalty by 1 and 2 respectively.

I don't recall ever finding any, I learned how to make them from the book "[Needle and Thread](https://7daystodie.gamepedia.com/Perk_Books#Needle_.26_Thread) vol 7" and crafted them myself.

Comment: Ah, one of the first skills I got is 'Pack Mule' so I never really paid attention to those type of mods.  The actual mods as of A19 are 'Clothing Pocket Mod' which gives 1 slot and I think you can make from the start and 'Clothing Double Pocket Mod' which is from Needle & Thread 7.  Thanks!   Looking through the xml config the duster has the 'pocketMod' tag and those are the only two mods that have that in 'installable_tags' so that should be a complete list.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat Yeah, as I mentioned it's been a few versions since I last played, and they were pretty new at the time, so I'm not surprised that they gave them less confusing names.

Comment: There's also a triple pocket, and you can actually max out your inventory using just mods.

Comment: Yes, there are separate single, double, and triple pocket mods that work in armor.

Answer (score -1):

According to [the wiki entry on mods](https://7daystodie.gamepedia.com/Mods), mods can only be used on **Armor**, specifically Light Armor or Heavy Armor, and not items that are classified as Clothing or Apparel.

The [Leather Duster](https://7daystodie.gamepedia.com/Leather_Duster) specifically is grouped under Clothing and Apparel, and therefore can't have any Armor mods applied to it, despite having a Modifier slot.